# Scala throws no type parameters error on valid lambda definition

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The following method definition:

```
  def validClasses(dataType: DataType) = {
    examples
      .flatMap {
        v: Any =>
          Try {
            val canon = toCanonicalType(v, dataType)
            canon.getClass
          }
            .toOption
            .toSet
      }
  }
```

yield the following error:

```
Error:(94, 8) no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: Any => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Any => scala.collection.immutable.Set[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 })
 --- because ---
argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
 found   : Any => scala.collection.immutable.Set[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 }
 required: Any => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
      .flatMap {
   ^
```

Which is strange. As the result of toSet is not a a Set[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 }. Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: if you don't provide the type of `examples` how could anyone possibly answer your question?

Comment: Looks like the right type to me.  What type do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

> As the result of toSet is not a a Set[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 }.

Yes, it is: `.getClass` returns a `Class[_]`, so `Try { ... }` is a `Try[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 }` (`?0` is just a variable name generated by the compiler), and `.toOption.toSet` is a `Set[Class[?0]] forSome { type ?0 }`.